# Sklearn or my computer can't handle data set

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a data set of 100,000 rows and 125 features and continuous output. I'm running numpy, pandas, and sklearn on 2013 macbook pro with 16gb ram. Using only 10,000 rows and 5 features to train, the ipython kernel dies when I try to predict only 1,000 rows in the test set using sklearn RandomForestClassifier. Should I be hitting this limit with only 10,000 x 5 to train and 1,000 x 5 to predict?

[data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/allstate-claims-severity/data)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv') 
cat = df.iloc[:,:117]
cont = df.iloc[:,117:df.shape[1]-1]
y = df.iloc[:,df.shape[1]-1]
cat2 = df2.iloc[:,:117]
cont2 = df2.iloc[:,117:df2.shape[1]]

cont_new = SelectKBest(k=5).fit_transform(cont,y)
test = cont2.iloc[:,[6,7,10,12,13]]
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1,n_estimators=100,max_depth=20)
y = np.asarray(y,dtype="|S6")
rf.fit(cont_new[:10000], y[:10000])
predictions = rf.predict(test[:5000])
print(predictions)
```

Comment: Does it give any error before dying? Share the error. Also double check sampled data isn't faulty.

Comment: Open the Activity Monitor on your Mac - does it use an excessive amount of RAM when running?

Comment: I would try and run this outside of the ipython kernel and learn if the fault might be there.

Comment: The error message is "The kernal appears to have died. It will restart automatically." It runs in a script from the console but still takes forever with only 10,000 x 5 predictions.

Comment: Show the code or everything else is guessing.

Answer (score 0):

### Using memory_profiler to Diagnose Memory Usage

Just as [Robert Kern’s line_profiler package](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) measures CPU usage, the [memory_profiler module by Fabian Pedregosa and Philippe Gervais](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler/0.9) measures memory usage on a line-by-line basis. Understanding the memory usage characteristics of your code allows you to ask yourself two questions:

- Could we use less RAM by rewriting this function to work more efficiently?
- Could we use more RAM and save CPU cycles by caching?

`memory_profiler` operates in a very similar way to `line_profiler,` but runs far more slowly. If you install the `psutil` package (optional but recommended), `memory_profiler` will run faster. Memory profiling may easily make your code run 10 to 100 times slower. In practice, you will probably use `memory_profiler` occasionally and line_profiler (for CPU profiling) more frequently.

Install `memory_profiler` with the command `pip install memory_profiler` (and optionally `pip install psutil).`

As mentioned, the implementation of `memory_profiler` is not as performant as the implementation of `line_profiler`. It may therefore make sense to run your tests on a smaller problem that completes in a useful amount of time.

Overnight runs might be sensible for validation, but you need quick and reasonable iterations to diagnose problems and hypothesize solutions.

The requirement to modify the source code is a minor annoyance. As with `line_profiler,` a decorator `(@profile)` is used to mark the chosen function.

When dealing with memory allocation, you must be aware that the situation is not as clear-cut as it is with CPU usage. Generally, it is more efficient to overallocate memory to a process into a local pool that can be used at leisure, as memory allocation operations are relatively expensive. Furthermore, garbage collection is not instant, so objects may be unavailable but still in the garbage collection pool for some time.

The outcome of this is that it is hard to really understand what is happening with memory usage and release inside a Python program, as a line of code may not allocate a deterministic amount of memory as observed from outside the process. Observing the gross trend over a set of lines is likely to lead to better insight than observing the behavior of just one line.

Above is taken from [High performance Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449361595) by Micha Gorelick and Ian Ozsvald (pp. 42-50).